# Why does using a form input rather than static string prevent my code from generating a qr code?

Tags: javascript, angular

Trying to pass a text input value from my form to a JS library to process a qr code does not work. Adding a static value works all the time. How do I make it so that the value from my form works. For example making `text = "2743987947"` or `text = text = "hello"` works.
Console logging the input value gives me the correct value. However using this value to create a qr code fails.

Here is my code.

````
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  designForm: FormGroup;
  printForm: FormGroup;
  qrcodeImage;
  load: boolean;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.designForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      model: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      color: [
        '',
        Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern('[\\w\\-\\s\\/]+'),
        ]),
      ],
      space: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      serial1: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      serial2: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    });

    this.printForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [
        '',
        Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern('Martin Tecno'),
        ]),
      ],
    });
    this.qrcodeImage = this.createQrcode();
  }

  createQrcode() {
    let text = this.designForm.value.serial1;
    let typeNumber = 4;
    let errorCorrectionLevel = 'H';
    let qr = qrcode(typeNumber, errorCorrectionLevel);
    qr.addData(text);
    qr.make();
    //  return qr.createTableTag();
    // return qr.createSvgTag();
    return qr.createImgTag();
  }

  onSubmit(designForm) {
    console.log(designForm);
    console.log(this.qrcodeImage);
    console.log(this.designForm.value.serial1);
  }
}```
````

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? What have you tried to resolve this problem?

Comment: _“Console logging the input value gives me the correct value.”_ - you mean inside the `onSubmit` handler? But that is not where you call `createQrcode` …

Comment: you need put the `this.qrcodeImage = this.createQrcode();` INSIDE the submit function

Comment: you are calling the createQrcode when component is initialing ngOnInit. I think you just need to change where you call method "createQrcode "